# verilog design of ALU with FSM

Tags: verilog

I am designing an ALU with a FSM control unit. There are 2 control inputs mentioned namely Modes which decide the word size of the operation and the other input to  it is the Operations which decide the kind of operation to be performed.

I have attached the image of the ALU module which has to  be designed.
Do I  have to include a clock signal as well?
Is FSM always a sequential circuit?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes you have to include a clock signal. Please note that FSM is a sequential circuit that consist of a combinational logic along with flops. So clock is very much essential for the working of an FSM.

I could not see your attached image, but what I mentioned was in general, which is valid for every FSM.

For the diagram above, representing a Mealey FSM, the sequential logic is nothing but a block of Flops which takes next_state as input and flops it as state on the next cycle. The Combinational logic is the one which decides the logic of the next state.

Your sequential logic should be coded as

```
always@(posedge clock or negedge rst)
begin
  if(!rst)  state <= RESET_STATE;
  else      state <= next_state;   
end
```

//i.e if reset is asserted low, then state should follow next_state

And then the combinational logic should create a relation between state and next_state

```
always@*
begin
   case(state)
       RESET_STATE: ...
                    next_state = SOME_STATE;
```